# How get bottom y coordinate

Tags: ios, uiview, coordinate

How can I get the bottom left coordinate, i.e. the maximum y coordinate, of a view in obj-c and Swift?

Answer (score 61):

Supposing that you're talking about `UIView`, you may want to look at the [`CGGeometry`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGGeometry/Reference/reference.html) reference.

Talking about 'left' and y coordinate doesn't make much sense, but for instance

```
CGRectGetMaxY(view.frame) // will return the bottommost y coordinate of the view
CGRectGetMinX(view.frame) // will return the leftmost x coordinate of the view
```

and so on. You get the idea.

In Swift, this is even more convenient, as you can do

```
view.frame.maxY // will return the bottommost y coordinate of the view
view.frame.minX // will return the leftmost x coordinate of the view
```

Comment: This can be achieved even more easily with `view.frame.maxY` and `view.frame.minX`

Comment: True, that's only available in swift, though

Comment: typo I guess but the Swift version would be minX instead of minY

Comment: if it is a subview and you get an incorrect value, try it: bounds.  `view.bounds.maxY`

Answer (score 17):

It depends on what you want the coordinate in reference to. If you want the bottom left coordinate in your view's superview you could get the left and bottom with:

`view.frame.origin.x` for the left coordinate

and

`view.frame.origin.y + view.frame.size.height` for the bottom coordinate