# How to get bottom edge of the view?

Tags: ios, swift

I looked at the following post in order to understand how to get the y-coordinate of the bottom edge of a view: [How get bottom y coordinate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17332622/how-get-bottom-y-coordinate)

It says I can do this: `exampleView.frame.maxY`

However, when I do this I get 0. Here is my example:

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        let thankYouMessage = UILabel()
        self.view.addSubview(thankYouMessage)

        thankYouMessage.text = "Thank You for Installing the Keyboard"
        thankYouMessage.textAlignment = .Center

        thankYouMessage.snp_makeConstraints { (make) -> Void in
            make.right.left.top.equalTo(self.view)
            make.height.equalTo(self.view.frame.height * 0.2)
        }

        print(thankYouMessage.frame.maxY)

        let enableMessage = UILabel()
        self.view.addSubview(enableMessage)
        enableMessage.text = "Enable the keyboard here:"
        enableMessage.textAlignment = .Center
        enableMessage.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()

        enableMessage.snp_makeConstraints { (make) -> Void in
            make.left.equalTo(self.view)
            make.top.equalTo(self.view).offset(50)
            make.width.equalTo(self.view.frame.width * 0.3)
            make.height.equalTo(self.view.frame.height * 0.1)
        }




    }
```

The `print(thankYouMessage.frame.maxY)` returns 0.

I am not sure why this is. Is there some sort of initialization process I need to do to the first view?

Comment: Have you tried the second answer in that question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The view's frame isn't updated based on its constraints and/or its intrinsic content size until the layout pass has run.  The earliest you can get the view's on-screen frame in the view controller is in the `viewDidLayoutSubviews` method.

You could call `layoutIfNeeded` or `sizeToFit` on the view before asking for its frame, but depending on the situation those could still end up giving the wrong answer if called in `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: So would I put all of my custom constraint code in the `viewDidLayoutSubViews` method?

Comment: No, set up your constraints differently. You're constraining attributes to constants (e.g. `self.view.size.height * 0.2` is the view's **current** size which is then treated as a constant). Instead you should constrain attributes to attributes. Example: `thankYouMessage.heightAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.2).active = true`

Answer (score 0):

It happened  because you created your label with zero frame and your view is not added to hierarchy in the window in viewDidLoad method. The documentation say's that in viewDidLoad view has been loaded only into memory. And in viewWillAppear it added to hierarchy in the window. Put your print to viewWillAppear for check it or created UILabel() with frame